# Python dynamic module import

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic, import, python-import

I have a file called `route_configs.py` where I use a relative import to a module called `schemas` the following way:

```py
from .. import schemas, services

...

xy = RouteConfig(
    ...
    schemas=schemas.users
    ...
)
```

In schemas I have the following code in `__init__.py`:

```py
from .users import users
...
```

And my goal is to import `users` from `schemas` dynamically, like:

```py
from .. import schemas, services

...

xy = RouteConfig(
    ...
    schemas=schemas['users'] # obviously this won't work
    ...
)
```

Because I'll have a list of routes and I'd like to iterate over them and set the `RouteConfig` dynamically using only the name of the route (in this case `users`).

Is there any way I can do this easily and without defining the full path of there modules (and keep the relative import, so this can be a separate 'module)'.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with `eval`, like this:

```py
from .. import schemas, services

...

xy = RouteConfig(
    ...
    schemas=eval(f'schemas.{endpoint.get("name")}')
    ...
)
```

Although I don't think this is the best solution, but it's ok for now.